# Using Javascript to display weights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function that changes a user preference, if they want weights to be metric or in imperial.

On my page I print out the weight, IE:

```
This is some description:

This product weights <b>200 KG</b>

Blah blah
```

I need to make it so that Javascript changes the weight measurement for all weights on the page, and am not sure the best way to tackle this.  Can you create your own tags, or tag properties?

Thanks for any suggestions, JQuery is fine.

Comment: Are there many such weights throughout your app? Are they autogenerated?

Comment: off-topic tip: `<b>` is deprecated, you should use `strong`.

Comment: Also off-topic, FWIW: "kg" is the correct symbol for kilograms (rather than "KG"). But most people will neither notice nor care. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend using `strong` rather than `b`, but the below will work for either of them.

**Edit**: Better solution than using a class, with working example, below.

<s>Tag the weights with a class, e.g.:</s>

```
This product weighs <strong class='weight'>200 KG</strong>
```

Then in your JavaScript, you can switch like so:

```
$('.weight').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var original = $this.text();
    var converted = /* ...convert the weight here... */;
    $this.text(converted);
});
```

Obviously you can condense that a bit, kept it verbose for clarity.

**Better solution:**

Tag the elements with the original weight (the one you store in your database) as a `data-weight` attribute, e.g.:

```
This product weighs <strong data-weight='200'>200 KG</strong>
```

Then convert from that value:

```
$('[data-weight]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.attr("data-weight");
    if (usingMetric) {
        $this.text(value + " KG");
    }
    else {
        value = parseFloat(value) * 2.20462262; // Convert to imperial
        $this.text(value.toFixed(2) + " lbs");
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/icure3

Attributes in the form `data-xyz` will pass [validation](http://validator.w3.org) as of HTML5; prior to HTML5 they are technically invalid, but harmless. But if you prefer a version that doesn't use `data-weight`, you can do it with classes instead: http://jsbin.com/icure3/2 (inspired by [Reigel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750101/jquery-error-data-weight-is-null/3750180#3750180) to Tom's other question).

If you see a delay when switching between metric and imperial on slower browsers (I'm looking at you, Microsoft), you can help jQuery's selector engine optimize by giving it more context than just "[data-weight]". jQuery's engine supports nearly all of [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/). For instance, if you always use the `data-weight` attribute only one one kind of tag (say, `strong` tags), change the selector to "strong[data-weight]" so the selector engine knows it can optimize for just one specific tag name. Similarly, if all of these are inside some container (e.g., a div with the ID "productList" for instance), you can help the engine out even more ("#productList strong[data-weight]") so it can ignore anything outside that div. I've kept it completely general above. But probably only bother if the page is big and complex enough that you see a performance issue.

Final thought: To throw a bone to browsers with JavaScript disabled, you might include *both* values in a `title` attribute as well, e.g.:

```
This product weighs <strong title='200 KG / 441 lbs' data-weight='200'>200 KG</strong>
```

...so it shows up as a tooltip on browsers that do that. I included that in the example above.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but I get the error: "Error: $("[data-weight]") is null" when I try and run this in "the jQuery(document).ready(function() {" function

Comment: @Tom: Try to run it where? It works on JSBin. Tested on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera on Linux, and IE6 (!) and IE8 on Windows, I figure if all of those work, it should be pretty cross-browser... :-) If you're doing it on your own site, did you include jQuery? The above assumes you're using it, since you said that was okay in the question.

Comment: Thanks Crowder, yes I am using Jquery, I'll do a new question for it though as it's a different problem

Comment: @Tom: Added a note about performance. You probably won't see an issue, but for the sake of completeness...

Answer (score 4):

I would add a class `.weight` and use this to target all the weights..

```
$('.weight').each(function(){...})
```

If you want to change the `innerHTML` you can use the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method directly

```
$('.weight').html(function(idx, oldhtml){
 // you can use the oldhtml to extract info and create the new text here..
  $(this).html( ../*you new html here*/.. ); // replace existing with new html ..
})
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty new to Jquery, how do you access the inner HTML of each weight div?  I should be ok from there

Comment: @Tom, note that @T.J. Crowder has provided a complete solution at the end of his answer.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<b class="weight">200 KG</b>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#UnitChangeButton").click(function() {
  $('.weight').each(function(){
    txt = $(this).text();
    newTxt = convert(txt);
    $(this).text(newTxt);
  });
});
```

You need to implement the convert function. You can store the state (metric or imperial) in a javascript variable.