# Jquery Error: $("[data-weight]") is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Stripped a ton of stuff to make it more readable, it throws an error on the line:

```
$('[data-weight]').each(function() {
```

Saying that it is null

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 
    1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="ctl00_mainHead">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jqueryv1.4.2.js"></script>

           <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                $('[data-weight]').each(function() {

                    var usingMetric = false;

                    var $this = $(this);
                    var value = $this.attr("data-weight");
                    if (usingMetric) {
                        $this.text(value + " KG");
                    }
                    else {
                        value = parseFloat(value) * 2.20462262; // Convert to imperial
                        $this.text(value + " lbs");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
     </head>

    <body>

    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="viewProduct.aspx?ID=3&amp;action=added" id="aspnetForm">


        <div class="productDetail">
            <b>Product Details</b>
        </div>

        <strong data-weight="200">800 KG</strong>


</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update**

It's a follow on my this question:

[Using Javascript to display weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749900/using-javascript-to-display-weights)

Comment: In XHTML 1.1, `strong` does not have a `data-weight` attribute. `data-`-prefixed attributes are about to be introduced with HTML 5.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is select all the elements on a page that have weights in them so I can dynamically convert them, the other question I linked to explains the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery's "no conflict" mode, the problem might be this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                                ^-- Consider adding $ here
```

...or use `jQuery` rather than `$` throughout.

If you're not using jQuery no-conflict, I'm not seeing why there'd be a problem. It works just fine here: http://jsbin.com/odaxa3 The only edits I made were to load jQuery from Google's CDN and to make the weight in the attribute match the display.

Comment: Thanks for the simplified example I'll try and work out why this isn't working

Comment: Ah adding the $ in the ready function works fine, thanks again! :=)

Answer (score 2):

`data-weight` is not a valid attribute, on before HTML5. How about doing it this way,

html part,

```
<strong class="weight-800">800 KG</strong>
```

jQuery part,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('[class^="weight"]').each(function () {

        var usingMetric = false;

        var $this = $(this);
        var value = this.className.split('-')[1];
        if (usingMetric) {
            $this.text(value + " KG");
        }
        else {
            value = parseFloat(value) * 2.20462262; // Convert to imperial
            $this.text(value + " lbs");
        }
    });
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqevX/)

Comment: `data-weight` is valid as of HTML5. Since he's declaring XHTML 1.1, I *think* you're technically correct, but I can't imagine a browser actually caring. But still, nice edit for being valid pre-HTML5.

Comment: Are you sure about that `this.class().split('-')[1];` line? I'd think it should be `this.className.split('-')[1];` (e.g., `className` rather than `class` -- which is an invalid identifier in JavaScript -- and a property, not a function).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - haha fixed that, thanks... @Tom Gullen, please try... I have some corrections made.

Comment: I've created a variant of the live example of my answer to Tom's original question inspired by this: http://jsbin.com/icure3/2

Comment: @Reigel: LOL, we should have teamed up -- I see you did a jsFiddle. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Reigel, it's a good demo I've +1 you but TJ had the solution to the error

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting the units, you could print all units and only display the one that is preferred:

```
<strong><span class="metric">800 kg</span> <span class="units-separator">/</span> <span class="imperial">1763 lbs</span></strong>
```

Now you can switch between the units by displaying/hiding the elements with the class *metric*‍/‍*imperial*:

```
.units-separator { display: none }
/* for metric view */
.metric { }
.imperial { display: none }
/* for imperial view */
.metric { display: none }
.imperial { }
```

And if CSS is not supported, both units are shown as:

> 800 kg / 1763 lbs

Comment: Now that's a cute idea. I prefer the conversion route, but it's great to give the OP (good!) alternatives.

Comment: How do you switch the classes dynamically?

Comment: @Tom Gullen: You could add a class name like “metric-units”/‍“imperial-units” to `BODY` and change the mentioned CSS rules to `body.metric-units .metric {} body.metric-units .imperial { display: none }` and `body.imperial-units .metric { display: none } body.imperial-units .imperial { }`. Then you can toggle between the class names with `$(document.body).removeClass("imperial-units").addClass("metric-units")` and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

May i know,what is 'data-weight' ?  Is it a control ID? If it is control id then you need to give :

```
$('#data-weight').children().each(function() {...
```

Or

The following post might be helpful to you :

[jQuery attribute selectors: How to query for an attribute with a custom namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91518/jquery-attribute-selectors-how-to-query-for-an-attribute-with-a-custom-namespace)

Comment: Don't you see `<strong data-weight="200">`?